# Breaking up a large script into smaller batches

Tags: php, magento, logic

I have written a script for a magento store, it's purpose is to populate a .txt file, which is in turn read by Google Merchant Centre.

The script functions correctly, however the magento store is hosted on a crappy host which only allows 256MB per PHP instance. This cannot be changed, so the only solution I can see is to break the script up so it only processes a few products at a time, running as a cron job, every few minutes.

I'm struggling to think of an efficient way of doing this though. I can limit the number of products I select, but then next time the script runs it wont know what's been added to the .txt and what hasn't.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: why not just count lines in txt file and use it as an offset?

Answer (score 0):

A simple but maybe slightly dirty solution could be to add a simple "checkbox" column to the products table or have an extra table with just two columns, the product Id and a timestamp.
Then you could use the timestamp to order by and limit the number of rows fetched.

```
select productId, lastProcessed from productProcess order by lastProcessed asc limit 0,<whatever your limit>
```

Then when you process each row you can update the lastProcessed column with NOW().
If you don't want to continuously process the products you can use a checkbox column to mark when you've processed and then at a certain time just clear all the "checkboxes".

It adds to the processing time but this way you know for certain which products you have already processed.

These are just a couple of variants, you could come up with other solutions based on this.